# why C++ member function address is the same under release mode

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++14

```
class Test2
{
  public:

    void Test111(INT32 i)
    {
        i++;
    }
    void Test112(INT32 i)
    {
        i++;
    }
};

typedef void (Test2::* TestF)(int); 

/*main*/ 
int main()
{ 
  TestF val1 = &Test2::Test111; 
  TestF val2 = &Test2::Test112; 

  if(val1==val2) 
  { 
    /*in VS2019 release mode with Same Address*/ 
    printf("Same Address in VS2019 release mode"); 
  } 
  else 
  { 
    /*in VS2019 debug mode with Different Address*/ 
    printf("Different Address in VS2019 debug mode"); 
  } 
  return 0; 
};
```

Comment: %d is for int type, val1 and val2 are not int variables.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour of the example program is undefined. You may only use `int` (or similar) when using the format specifier `%d`. There is no format specifier for pointers to member functions.

Furthermore, a pointer to member function doesn't store "an address". Its structure is more complex than that. It  may involve one or more addresses and/or offsets, or whatever it is that the language implementation needs to implement it.

Comment: in debug mode val1 ！=val2 in release mode val1==val2

Comment: @牛仔不在 Create a [mcve]. The MCVE must not have undefined behaviour in order for it to meaningfully be able to demonstrate that they are equal. Otherwise the behaviour that it demonstrates is result of the behaviour being undefined.

Comment: The function execution body is consistent, maybe MSVC compiler optimization thinks it is the same function, if change the body the function address is different，speechless !!

Comment: @牛仔不在 Please add the code to the question, instead of in comments.

Comment: "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details"   After editing Stack Overflow doesn't allow me to submit it.